# How to disable SMTP debugging information in PHPMailer?

Tags: php

I am sending OTP through email in PHPMailer. everything is working fine but i am getting debug information in the page like this:

```
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP y14-20020a056a001c8e00b004fa829db45csm8785422pfw.218 - gsmtp
    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [49.34.88.171]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
    CLIENT -> SERVER: AUTH LOGIN
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6

    '
    '
    '
   CLIENT->SERVER :MORE INFORMATION
```

I used `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;` but still showing debug infromation.

```
     $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
     $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
```

anything i am missing that i should know?

Comment: I havent used PHPMailer in a long time, but i think it should be like this `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;`

Comment: @brunerPhone thanks but i checked my code again and found  `$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;` line somewhere after   `$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`  it was activating it again . i removed it and it worked:)

Answer (score 0):

as bruner said, just writing :

`$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_OFF;`

or

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;`

should enable the debugging mode

Are you sure that `$mail` is the only PHPMailer instance created?

Comment: Yes only instance was created  `$mail = new PHPMailer(true);`  but problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

```
SMTP::DEBUG_OFF (0):
```

Use this, this can disable debugging (you can also leave this out completely, 0 is the default).